# How to integrate Adobe Stock Integration in the Open Source 2.4-develop branch project?

Tags: magento2, page-builder, magento2.4, adobe-stock

Does anyone use the Adobe Stock Image Searchable Interface inside PageBuilder blocks?

Will it sync Magento's Catalog/WYSIWYG images with the Adobe Stock or will it work vice-versa.

Is it good to configure directly on the LIVE website?

Added composer changes to the `<magento-root>/composer.json` file as follows:

```
https://github.com/magento/adobe-stock-integration/blob/1.0.0-release/_metapackage/composer.json
```

After enabling all the required modules, a new button added into the page builder content section as Search Adobe Stock using the below plugin.

```
Magento\AdobeStockImageAdminUi\Plugin\AddSearchButton.php
```

Ref. https://github.com/magento/adobe-stock-integration/tree/1.0.0-release